# Missing QnA results in bot, but they show up in the log

Tags: botframework

I'm working with a QnA service bot, and I'm getting odd results.

To explain, I've pushed a large number of web pages and documents into it. I've been testing and publishing regularly, and this morning I posed a few questions that gave the "no good result in faq" message.

[image: bot]

However when I go into application insights, analytics, and look at the question log, I see my questions -- but with the correct answers next to them.

[image: log]
Why/how does that happen?

Comment: I'm sorry but your screenshot is not readable so it does not provide much information.

Comment: The gist of it is, I posed a series of questions to the front end of the bot and got a lot of "no matches found" messages. Then I ran a query against the database on questions, answers, result code, timestamp, duration. The questions I asked earlier showed up with the correct answers (not a "no matches found" error) alongside.

Answer (score 0):

In QnAMakerDialog, we can specify the [ScoreThreshold](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerService/QnAMakerAttribute.cs#L69) property that indicates the threshold for answer score, if the score of returned answer(s) is less than that threshold, bot would also display default message.

You can check if the mateched answer with a low confidence score. Besides, you can try to assign a smaller value to `ScoreThreshold` property.